# Wrote or has written/accused or have accused

Tags: word-usage

[image]This exercise is from "English Grammar in Context" by Michael Vince. Is it possible to use d. "wrote" instead of "have written", f. "were" instead of "have been", h. "have won" instead of "won", i. "was" instead of "has always been", j. "accused" instead of "have accused", k. both "has pointed out" and "pointed out" are correct according to the book, l. "wrote" instead of "has written"?

Comment: The present perfect is used because Ian McEwan is still alive. However, I would consider _wrote_ to be correct in (i) because Pynchon's article was written at a particular time.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, but isn't it possible to use "were successful" in f?

Comment: Does any one else dislike the term "present perfect simple"  Since the present perfect is not a simple tense! It is formed with an auxiliary verb.

Comment: Yes, I think it would be possible.